# Unable to open Slingshot after last update

Tags: applications, slingshot

I am unable to open the applications menu after the last update.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've fixed it....by using 'pkill slingshot' and rebooting

Comment: If solved, please post your own answer and accept it after 48 hrs :)

Answer (score 3):

If Slingshot doesn't respond you can restart it with the terminal command:

**In loki (0.4)**

```
killall wingpanel
```

**In freya (0.3)**

```
killall slingshot
```

It will be automatically restarted by the cerbere watchdog.

Comment: Typing "killall slingshot" in terminal gives "slingshot: no process found". This problem happens after each update. Any ideas are welcome, as it's rather unpleasant being forced to reboot every time an update occurs. Cheers

Comment: It is integrated in `wingpanel` now, you can restart it with `killall wingpanel`